# Best way to implement extension methods

Tags: linq, extension-methods, asp.net-4.0

I am really really *really* new to all of this, and most of it is unexplored territory. Today I needed to create an anonymous class and put it to a list. I was trying to find how I can make a list of anonymous types, and found that I should make an extension method. I also already figured out an extension method should be in a static class. But what I haven't figured out yet is if there is some pattern that I should use? For now, I have made a static class in my App_Code folder named ExtensionMethods, but have no idea if I should put extension methods of all kinds of types in this class, or if I should make separate classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can not implement extension methods for anonymous classes. And this makes sense as really and truly if the class has some semantics it should be made a named class.
To create a list of anonymous classes use this method:

```
public static List<T> CreateListFromType<T>(T anonType){
   return new List<T>();
}
```

To use this method to create a list, do something like:

```
var list = CreateListFromType(new {A = default(int), B = default(int)});
```

Comment: The important part here is that the compiler *infers* the type of `T` for a generic method, so it is possible. However, the LINQ `ToList` approach is probably always better.

Comment: Okay, so here's an idea that I got - instead of having a property and insisting it should be of return type List<someTypeHere>, I will make the return type a var. I can then have var query = ....ToList().

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a list of an anonymous class.

```
var anonList = new[]{
    new {Foo = "foo", Bar = 2},
    new { Foo = "bar", Bar = 3},
}.ToList();
```

It has nothing to do with writing extension methods.

**Edit:**
In fact you will have a hard time to use extension methods to create anonymous types since anonymous types can not be used as method parameters or return type.

**Edit2:**
If you want to convert a list of anonymous types to a list of specific types you can use Select:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int Prop2 {get;set;}
}

List<MyClass> myList = anonList.Select(x => new MyClass(){Prop1 = Foo, Prop2 = Bar}).ToList();
```

Comment: Right, If you can write in extension, you must be able to write inline.

Comment: Well, here's the thing: On my page I have a Listview that repeats the same DropDownList 8 times. I have an itemdatabound event in which I fill these ddl's. Instead of firing a query to the db with linq to fill the ddl's inside this event, I just want to make one call to the db, and have the resultset put away in a property with return type list<someTypeHere>. But the resultset is an anonymous type, and I would like the list to be List<somethingTypeHere> instead of just List.

Comment: @benjamin you cant do that. For storing a list of anonymous types you have to use the var keyword, and for returning it from a method it must be seen as a list of objects.

Comment: Right, okay - so... how do I go about it? How can I get my List of anonymous types at page scope?

Comment: You cant... i feel like im repeating my self here. There is a reason its called anonymous! Depending on you problem maybe you should look at using dynamic types instead?

Comment: "You cant... i feel like im repeating my self here" - no reason to be pedantic here. I appreciate your answer and I honestly thought there might be another way around. So I guess there's not. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: The var keyword can only be used in the scope of a method, so outside the method you have to have a static type. You can't for instance make a method look like public static var GetList() {}. In such case you have to either return object or IList. You can though, use reflection to loop through all the properties of your anonymous type, that is how ie MVC works for adding arbitrary attributes to html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Extension method is nothing more than *easier-to-read* static helper/utility methods. The way you organize them is the same principal as how you organize your normal classes. If you think those should stays together, then try to give them a meaningful, general enough name as the class name. Once you found your class name cannot include what that method doing, then you know that method should belongs to other places.

Comment: Okay, so I guess that in my case, for now at least, ExtensionMethod as a class is generic enough.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly extension methods are normal static methods declared like this -

```
void MyExtension(this MyTarget target, int myparam){ ..
```

After this the C# compiler adds some syntactic sugar letting you call this method as

```
target.MyExtension(myparam);
```

The compiler will replace all these calls with

```
MyStaticClass.MyExtension(target, myparam);
```

The important thing is that an extension method is a normal static method. You should follow following guidelines while creating them -

1. Try to group extension methods for each target class in a separate static class and name it appropriately as Extensions.
2. Create a new namespace in your application for Extension methods such as MyAppExtensions and keep your static classes inside this namespace. This will keep the coder from misunderstanding them as Extension method and accidentally using them as instance methods.
3. Make these naming conventions for namespaces and static classes of Extension methods as a standard in the team.
4. In your extension method check if the first parameter is null and take appropriate action. If you do not then it will be possible to call the method with target being null and may result in unexpected behavior. If the first parameter is allowed to be null then document it clearly.
5. Consciously decide if it is correct to create and extension method or instance method will be better.
6. Be careful that the extension method names do not clash with instance method names or other existing extension method names for this class. Following point 1, 2 and 3 will help you achieve this.

I learnt these from [Jon Skeet's C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/). You should read it too.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on C# in Depth. Heard a lot of good stories about it.

Answer (score 0):

I use to put anonymous to DataTable. Due to it's limitation, DataTable provide more functionality such as serialization.